# Is it possible to add a security url in a Mule Flow, like Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-security, mule, mule-studio

For example, in Spring I use the following code:

```
<http pattern="/users(?!\/emails).*" request-matcher="regex" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">

    <anonymous enabled="false" />

    <intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/user(?:([^/](?s).*)?)" />
```

So, on Mule I want to add security at the beginning of the Flow or (if possible), to configure the <intercept-url> tags.

And if possible, can I do this on Community Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question in points:-

1. Yes, it is possible in **Mule Community Edition** to add **security** using **Spring security** as it has support for **Basic Authentication**
   For your above requirement you need to implement **Spring security** in Mule
   Mule can be configured with **Spring security** to provide Basic Authentication with **username** and **password**.
2. Whenever you hit the service, it will ask for **username** and **password** for that service.
   So, this answer your question of implementing security at the **beginning** of the flow.

A simple example would be :-

```
<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <ss:authentication-provider>
        <ss:user-service id="userService">
          <ss:user name="john" password="abc123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
          <ss:user name="anon" password="anon" authorities="ROLE_ANON" />
        </ss:user-service>
      </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager> 
  </spring:beans>

  <mule-ss:security-manager>
      <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
  </mule-ss:security-manager>

  <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />

  <flow name="SpringExampleFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>      
    <logger level="INFO" message="passed security successfully !!! " doc:name="Logger"/>
  </flow>
</mule>
```

The spring security can also be configured to provide **role** based support where multiple users involve with `<mule-ss:authorization-filter/>`.
So, you can filter the users based on their **roles**.

Some example you can refer here to get more ideas on it and it's implementation :- http://confluex.com/blog/http-inbound-endpoint-basic-authentication/
and
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager

Comment: I have edited and tailed my previous answer.. now the answer is more user requirement specific

Comment: But, can I add a custom filter instead of basic security filter?

Comment: What type of custom filter you like to add ? Spring security will be easy to implement... for enterprise edition OAuth is there

Comment: What I need is: I have an API for authentication, when the authentication  will called, Mule will returns a SessionID. Mule will handle this session, and after the authentication, the requests should be filtering by `<mule-ss:authorization-filter/>` according to the role.

Comment: Yes you can either use that or you can code that in your api to return the session id and can accept the role in your request and validate on it.. You can configure whatever you like